# psiTurk on Chromebook with Ubuntu installed

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, chromebook

Trying to install python 2.7.13 and mysql on a Chromebook that has Ubuntu installed. However, when I update python it updates to 2.7.11 and says it's the newest version. Is there any way to update it other than `sudo apt-get install python`?